# air application AS3: save sounds as ringtones/notification

Tags: actionscript-3, ringtone, audio

im new to this. just made a two page soundboard. its working great. problem is that i would like to give the ability to save sounds as ringtones/notifications. no examples of how to do that in as3 are available. help please!

Comment: Hey there - I suspect no one has attempted to help because you've given very little information. There is no standard file type for ringtones (notifications?) and you'll have to choose one or two in order to define the problem. Saving a file to MP3 is a pretty advanced affair, saving to WAV slightly less so. You'll have to do some research into ByteArray and FileReference classes. One might assume you are loading the sounds into your app as MP3's so you may be closer than you think.

Answer (score 1):

- record a sound using : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858
- encode to mp3 using : https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy
- save mp3 data to file as such :

  ```
   private function saveFile()
      {       
      // WRITE ID3 TAGS

      var sba:ByteArray = mp3Encoder.mp3Data;
      sba.position =  sba.length - 128
      sba.writeMultiByte("TAG", "iso-8859-1");
      sba.writeMultiByte("Microphone Test 1-2, 1-2      "+String.fromCharCode(0), "iso-8859-1");  // Title
      sba.writeMultiByte("jordansthings                 "+String.fromCharCode(0), "iso-8859-1");  // Artist           
      sba.writeMultiByte("Jordans Thingz Bop Volume 1  "+String.fromCharCode(0), "iso-8859-1");   // Album        
      sba.writeMultiByte("2010" + String.fromCharCode(0), "iso-8859-1");                          // Year
      sba.writeMultiByte("www.jordansthings.com         " + String.fromCharCode(0), "iso-8859-1");// comments


      sba.writeByte(57);                                                                      
      filePath = (File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("sound3.mp3")).url;

      // get the native path 
      var wr:File = new File(filePath);
      // create filestream 
      var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
      //  open/create the file, set the filemode to write in order to save.
      stream.open( wr , FileMode.WRITE);
      // write your byteArray into the file. 
      stream.writeBytes ( sba, 0, sba.length );
      // close the file. 
      stream.close();

  }
  ```